# ¿Como realizar una consulta a una base de datos sensible a mayusculas/minusculas?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Quiero obtener el nommbre que se asocia a los datos de usuario y contraseña en una tabla a lo cual realizo la siguiente consulta en SQL Server.

```
select Nombre from usuarios where NombreUsuario  = 'UsuarioPrueba' and Contraseña = 'contRaPrueba';
```

El problema es que no importa si lo tengo con mayusculas o minusculas igual me trae el mismo dato

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta esto:

```
SELECT Nombre FROM usuarios 
  WHERE NombreUsuario  = 'UsuarioPrueba' AND 
        Contraseña = 'contRaPrueba' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

Comment: Me a servido mucho pero para que me funcione tanto en el usuario como en la contraseña puse de esta manera: select Nombre from usuarios where NombreUsuario  = 'UsuarioPrueba' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS and Contraseña = 'contRaPrueba' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;

Comment: si, es que funciona por cada campo diciéndole a la base de datos como es el orden o secuencia del contenido (en este caso letras) para una comparación

Comment: Puedes agregar el collation a la columna, alterando la tabla.